# What Java Mail JARs does my project require?

Tags: java, smtp, classpath, jakarta-mail, sendgrid

Trying to use [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) to send emails using the code example shown [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/java.html) which simply states I need "Java Mail".

I went [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR) and downloaded Java Mail 1.4.7. Inside that ZIP file is:

- `mail.jar`
- `lib/dsn.jar`
- `lib/gimap.jar`
- `lib/imap.jar`
- `lib/mailapi.jar`
- `lib/pop3.jar`
- `lib/smtp.jar`

I'm inclined to put all 7 JARs on my runtime classpath, but `mailapi.jar` and `mail.jar` seem to contain a lot of the same classes.

So I ask: **when one needs to Java Mail, which JARs need to be on the runtime classpath - and why?**

This is for a Java web app running on Tomcat 7.

Comment: You should check what apis you are using. On the basis of that you can decide which jars you can omit.

Comment: Per the code example I gave a link for, I need to import `javax.mail.*`, `javax.mail.internet.*`, `javax.mail.Authenticator`, and `javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication`. **Most importantly**, I need to understand when to use `mail.jar` and when `mailapi.jar` is sufficient, since those are the 2 JARs with the conflicting classes.

Comment: Also, even though all the classes I need to import are under the  `java.mail` package, I'm not sure if those classes transitively use the other JARs (which I assume they do).

Comment: With the package/class you provided above, I think using only mail.jar would do.

Comment: Thanks @GV (+1) - I will certainly give it a try, but at the core of this question is: why should I use `mail.jar` as opposed to `mailapi.jar`? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you understand the difference:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/notes-2-149762.txt

Comment: NOTES.txt is in the zip file you downloaded too, along with README.txt.  Did you find them?  And in case you're not aware, there's a newer version of JavaMail available [here](http://javamail.java.net).